# What's the best way to allow my child class access to it's parents information?

Tags: java, class, parent-child

This is my class structure at the moment.

[image]

***The player now needs some information on both the GUI and Table. How best can I do this?***

- Make the table static? (there will only ever be one table)
- Pass an instance of the table and the corresponding seat within the constructor of player?
- Pass the data needed for each method of players as arguments?

I would like to avoid restructuring my code to include intermediate classes or the likes if possible. At this point it would be a lot of effort. Thanks :)

---

edit:
***Just to clarify as my graph is crap.  The GUI contains one table instance, the table contains ten seats each seat may or may not contain a player. No inheritance has been used.***

Comment: It this would be an UML- class - diagram, it would mean Seat inherits from Player, Table from Seat and GUI from Table. But x1/x10 does more look like an cardinality from an ER diagram (10 seats per table, 1 Table per GUI, ? Player-Seat relation)? But you're talking about `childs` and `parents`. Who is a child of whom? Making table static would imply one table per JVM - not per GUI/JFrame which could be interesting when comparing different strategies played in parallel. Making something static is often a restriction to the far future.

Comment: @userunknown The GUI contains one table instance, the table contains ten seats each seat may or may not contain a player. No inheritance has been used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just passing the data the player needed as arguments within it's methods. I was definitely over-thinking things as I had only a small amount of data to pass on. If the data needed is more extensive look to one of the other answers.

This is a sample method within my table class that passes on two of it's own variables and one of seats variables to the Player class by calling one of Players methods that needs these variables.

```
seats[j].getPlayer().raise(raised, seats[j].getPosition(), inPlaySeats);
```

Answer (score 1):

i will choose the second option, Pass an instance of the table and the corresponding seat within the constructor of player.

Comment: How would I keep the copies of my table instances synchronized? I'd need to update all 1-11 of them if I were to do this wouldn't I?
Add in the seat instances and my program doesn't look very OO anymore.

Comment: sorry for my late respond. you don't need to update all your table instances,. they will be updated automatically. if you are using some threads, you need to add the 'synchronized' in the method in shich the table value may change,.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're doing, I would think that the GUI would have an instance of a table, a table would have an array of seats and players would be assigned a position in the array of seats that the table has. The table could have public methods to provide the player with information that the player may need regarding the table and the other players in the array of seats. The GUI could provide the player with information about the table and all players via public methods in the table, seat and player classes. I don't really see how table, seat and player can be child classes of GUI since, I assume, GUI is a GUI and has no ther function than to display and provide a means of user input.

Comment: How would the players access the tables public methods unless the table was static?

Comment: The Seat class has an instance of a player as a member, the Table class has, for example, an array of Seat objects as a member and the Player class has a reference to the table that the player is seated at. The reference to the Table held by the Player class can be used to access the public methods of the Table class. That's a simple example of how the public methods of the Table class can be called from the Player class.

Comment: How would I go about making a reference of the table? As creating an instance would create a copy that will not keep up to date won't it?

Comment: Simple example. The Player class has a member that is a Table called, "playersTable" and when you create or add a Player object to a Seat at the Table you can pass in a reference to the Table the player is seated at in the Player constructor or use a method on the Player class to set the reference to the Table. example; Player.setPlayersTable(table) where "table" is an instance of the Table class that has already been created. Then the Player can use the reference to call public methods of the Table like so, playersTable.getPlayerName(seatNumber) to get the name of a player at a specific seat.

Answer (score 0):

If Player extends Seat, Seat extends Table, and Table extends GUI, then Player should have access to all of the (public) information contained in its parents. This is the basic idea of Object Oriented (OO) programming.

Making Table static would probably hurt you in the long run. If refactoring your code to what is suggested above is too difficult, then I would suggest you 2nd bullet point (pass a Table and Seat to the constructor of Player).

Comment: Sorry I think I made the graph wrong. I've updated the question. No inheritance has been used.

Comment: It seems like inheritance is exactly what you need. Have you tried refactoring your domain objects so that they extend each other, like they do in the diagram? Usually it's better to implement your code as you see it on paper.

Comment: There is one potential problem. I want the player class to be as lightweight as possible as I may be saving instances of it to an SQL database or making it parcelable in a later update.
That and it may be a little overkill, all the player class needs is one or two ints from both the table and seat instances above it.

Comment: It still wouldn't hurt to extend your base classes. Extending will not make Person much "heavier" (depends on how much data is contained in your superclasses), and as far as saving you only need to save the items in Person if you want to. You'll even have the option to save items from superclasses of Person since you'll have the references available. I always think it's best to design your code the same way you see it on a paper/whiteboard. And from your picture, it seems to me that you are envisioning your objects as having parent/child relationships, so why not do the same in your code? :)

Answer (score 0):

Make the fields that Player needs protected. This will allow Player to access Table and GUI's info.

Comment: Sorry my graph may look misleading. I haven't used inherithance. Should I have?